# ir code to hex usable by IrRemote lib

Tags: arduino, hex, infrared

I'm sending an ir signal on an arduino using this [IrRemote library](https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote). it works with the example send code "irsend.sendSony(0xa90, 12);" but i dont know how to get the other codes into a single hex format like the "0xa90". The codes for sony12 tv's from [irdb](http://irdb.tk) are in a much different format.

for example in "pronto hex": `0000 0068 0000 000D 0060 0018 0030 0018 0018 0018 0030 0018 0018 0018 0030 0018 0018 0018 0018 0018 0030 0018 0018 0018 0018 0018 0018 0018 0018 0408`

or another form of hex `00 00 1B 00 C8 04 04 B0 01 2C 02 58 01 2C 01 2C 01 2C 01 2C 32 64 8D 01 21 21 22 12 22 30`

I dont really understand how to get either of these formats into the value of "0xa90". If only there was a converter online.

Answer (score -2):

used irScrutinizer to translate the hex into the format the irRemote library needed. 
got the answer from the irRemote github help
https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote/issues/566

Comment: This doesn't help.